# Hibernate: Getting error after configuring Data Source in Weblogic "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update"

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, datasource, hibernate-envers

My application was running properly when I was configuring `Hibernate.cfg.xml` without any DataSource.
I am deploying my application on Weblogic.
But now I have configured it using a Data Source, (both in .cfg as well as Weblogic).
Aster this suddenly I have started getting the exception when update on some table is happening. Without the DataSource its working fine.

This was the **old** config: (works fine)

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision">true</property>
```

Following is the **new** config: (throws exception)

```
<property name="connection.datasource">DataSourceTest</property>
    <property name="jndi.class">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision">true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>  -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

**I have made the similar cofiguration in Weblogic 12.1.3 also**

But now its giving the following exception:

```
2016-07-20 14:45:02 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-07-20 14:45:02 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 17004, SQLState: 99999
2016-07-20 14:45:02 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Invalid column type: 16
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update
```

*All the `Select` and `Insert` queries are working just fine, but when the `update` happens, the above error is thrown.*

**My `Lib` folder contains the Hibernate Jar, JPA 2.1 jar**.

Is it some issue with the configuration I am doing?
All my mappings and columns etc seems to be fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try changing your dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect. This error is supposed to be thrown by the Boolean type

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correct answer.. !!! Just after posting this question I changed the Dialect to 10g...and it worked....

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov : Could you explain what you meant by `Boolean type error` . I am not finding any such clue. How is this exception related to the Dialect ?

Comment: Yes it is a conversion problem. In Oracle there is no boolean notation , so you need to tell your driver how to map from java Boolean to the Oracle boolean which just happens to be Char(1) or Number(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello the problem is coming from the fact that support of boolean in Oracle is either CHAR(1) or alternatively NUMBER(1). Which basically means that you will either have '1'-'0' or 'Y' -'N' combinations respectively. The problem is a conversion problem the JDBC driver needs to know how to convert your boolean into the CHAR(1)/NUMBER(1)

You can try the following:
1. Set your dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Alternatively you can try to convert the Number(1)/Char(1):

@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="true_false")
@NotNull
boolean value;

or

@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="yes_no")
@NotNull
boolean value;

Comment: :Isn't `OracleDialect` a generic version of `Oracle10gDialect`? Is it that the 10g dialect acts differently which is causing this issue.